# How to clear text from a search textbox after search is complete in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two dropdown lists and two textboxes

```
Search By: ByHtml.DropDownList("Search1", "Please Select...")
        Html.TextBox("searchString1")    

Search By: Html.DropDownList("Search2", "Please Select...")
        @Html.TextBox("searchString2")

        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
```

When I make my selection from whichever DDL and type text into the textbox and hit filter my search returns, however after the search the text remains in the textbox, is there a way of clearing it after the search so that the textbox is empty again? I tried

```
ModelState.Remove("");
```

but it didn't work.

A sample from My controller code is

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    // GET: /Main/
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString1, string searchString2, string Search1, string Search2)
    {
       //Create a Dropdown list
        var SearchOptionList = new List<string>();
        SearchOptionList.Add("LandLord");
        SearchOptionList.Add("Postcode");
        SearchOptionList.Add("Street Address");
        ViewBag.Search1 = new SelectList(SearchOptionList);
        ViewBag.Search2 = new SelectList(SearchOptionList);

var mylist = from m in "mydatabase" select m;

//This statement runs if the user selects a parameter from Search2 and leaves Search1 empty
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Search1) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Search2))
        {
            if (Search2 == "Postcode")
            {
                mylist = mylist.Where(s => s.Postcode.Contains(searchString2));
            }
            if (Search2 == "LandLord")
            {
                mylist = mylist.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString2));
            }
            if (Search2 == "Street Address")
            {
                mylist = mylist.Where(s => s.StreetAddress.Contains(searchString2));
            }
        }

  return View(mylist.ToList());
```

}

Comment: you can do it in you controller, share your controller code as well for answer

Comment: I've updated my question with some sample code from my controller

Comment: What is your model class? Normally, you should just clear the values in the object of the model class that gets passed back to your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should have a view model containing properties `searchString1` and `searchString2` and the select lists

```
public class SearchVM
{
  public string searchString1 { get; set; }
  public string searchString2 { get; set; }
  public SelectList SearchList1 { get; set; }
  public SelectList SearchList2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
  SearchVM model = new SearchVM();
  model.SearchList1 = new SelctList(...);
  model.SearchList2 = new SelctList(...);
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model SearchVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.searchString1, Model.SearchList1, "--Please select--")
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.searchString2, Model.SearchList2, "--Please select--")
  ....
}
```

Post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchVM model)
{
  // to clear all modelstate and reset values
  ModelState.Clear();
  model.searchString1 = null;
  model.searchString2 = null;
  // or to clear just one property and reset it
  ModelState.Remove("searchString1");
  model.searchString1 = null;
  // repopulate select lists if your returning the view
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stephen, I've updated my post again to show my class, I tried to adapt your changes into mine but I was getting some errors as I've already got an @model within my View page

Comment: The view model can contain these and your other properties as well, but it hard to understand what you are doing here. Do you want to have the search controls and the filtered list you return (in which case you should be using ajax) or do you want to select the search parameters and redirect to another view that displays the filtered list (without the search controls)?

Comment: When I select say postcode from the dropdown list and type in BT1 and hit search it will return all the relevant postcodes, however BT1 remains inside the search box, all I want is for this to be cleared once the search returns the postcodes

Comment: If you have a model then `ModelState.Clear();` will work as per my answer, but as you do not have a model (just 2 parameters in the method) I'm not sure if it works - but you could try it. Another option if you don't want to use a view model is to use javascript to clear the value.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of my `public ActionResult Index` method but before `return View()` I placed the following code which worked perfectly

```
 ModelState.Remove("searchString1");
        ModelState.Remove("searchString2");
        ModelState.Remove("Search1");
        ModelState.Remove("Search2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question, but I fall in the same issue. So I put my solution.

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @autofocus = "autofocus" })
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Search= null;
ModelState.Remove("Search");
return View(list.ToList());
```

Hope to help someone